# does mono run on 64-bit linux? any issues?

Tags: ubuntu, mono, 64-bit

I need to run/develop a mono-based application on a new dedicated server, and the ISP I usually use only offers 64bit Linux (of which I'll take Ubuntu)

Is there any problems running mono on this configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using Mono2.4 for a while on 64-bit OpenSUSE 11.1, with no particular problem.

An instance of that was a client/server architecture on top of an SVN server (with hook-scripts called by the server, sending messages over the network). So it used multithreading, network TCP/IP sessions, a bit of cryptography, basic GUI configuration windows, serializing, a little bit of reflection.

The only issue was a difference on how the windows forms were behaving in comparison to their .NET equivalent, but this is nothing to do with 64-bit/32-bit.

I did encounter a few problems when accessing an external C++ dynamic library, had to review the marshalling of a few pointers with a sloppy implementation (my mistake).

Are there specific libraries you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the source and compiled on 64bit redhat. Works perfectly.